# Pandas - Drop duplicate rows from a DataFrame based on a condition from a Series by keeping prioritized values

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following DataFrame:

```
ID    Color
1     Red
2     Yellow
1     Green
3     Red
1     Green
2     Red
```

And let's presume that the priority of the colors is as following:

```
Green > Yellow > Red
```

I want to remove rows with duplicate IDs by keeping the one, for which the color has the highest priority. So, for this example I would like to get this result:

```
ID    Color
1     Green
2     Yellow
3     Red
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this by using pandas functions? I've done a lot of research on the Internet, including the pandas documentation, but couldn't think of a good approach. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: for your example assuming ID is index `df.Color.sort_index().drop_duplicates(keep='last')` will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this atleast two ways once you have set your colors to category dtype with an order.

```
df['Color'] = pd.Categorical(df['Color'], categories=['Red','Yellow','Green'], ordered=True)
```

Option 1:

```
df.sort_values('Color', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['ID'])
```

Output:

```
   ID   Color
4   1   Green
1   2  Yellow
3   3     Red
```

Option 2:

```
df.groupby('ID')['Color'].max()
```

Output:

```
ID
1     Green
2    Yellow
3       Red
Name: Color, dtype: object
```

Comment: Have change another way :-) btw , still think `Categorical` is neat :-)

Comment: Many thanks for the tips. Gotta try it and see how it works

Answer (score 2):

You may need Using `map`, create your own order `dict` and `drop_duplicates`

```
df.iloc[df.Color.map({'Red':0,'Yellow':1,'Green':2}).argsort()].drop_duplicates('ID',keep='last')
Out[607]: 
   ID   Color
3   3     Red
1   2  Yellow
4   1   Green
```